# Nature of absorption spectra peaks similar profile in Dimethyl sulfide (C$_2$H$_6$S)

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, chemical-compounds

I was reading [interesting article](https://bigthink.com/13-8/james-webb-space-telescope-life-chemistry-strange-world/) about possible life signs detection in exoplanets, where JWS telescope have captured that exoplanet **K2-18 b** atmosphere has Dimethyl sulfide traces. This chemical element in Earth is only produced biologically, mostly in seas/oceans by Phytoplankton, having some specific smell, hence,- "sea smell". You know it :-)

Anyway, I was checking from curiosity an absorption/transmittance IR spectra of [Dimethyl sulfide](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/inchi?ID=C75183&Mask=80#IR-Spec), chemical formula C$_2$H$_6$S, which is given below.

[image]

Peaks pair centered at 1000 cm$^{-1}$ and 1360 cm$^{-1}$ have very similar profiles, while third absorption location group at about 2880 cm$^{-1}$ looks like it also "would be similar," if not potential peak would be removed from existence at 2880 cm$^{-1}$.

Basic question is, why group **I** and **II** have very similar absorption profiles. What's the driving force behind such similarity? An additional question, if it's possible to answer, is:  Why does group **III** have this middle absorption blockage wall missing?

Is this somehow related to the organic molecule's shape symmetry?

[image]

So that compounds CH$_3$ gives similar but shifted vibrational energy levels, or other reasons?

I hope answer will be not too much chemical; otherwise I should probably move this question to [chemistry.stackexchange.com](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is just a coincidence. There is, in general, no real connection between the shapes and profiles of peaks arising from excitations of different vibrational modes. All we can say is that the typical peak shape for a "rotation less" IR transition should be a Lorentzian peak and that coupling between vibrational modes of similar energies leads to splitting.

Comment: I see. But is it possible to find-out  _why_ **I**,and **II** absorption group profiles is like a scaled version of each other ? Is there a physical reason why different parts in spectra can match/overlap between themselves ? This is the main post question. What if 3 or 4 or more peak series shapes would match with other spectra parts ? There is a limit when we really need an explanation, because joint probability of pure coincidences decreases over adjacent matching peak number increase as a geometric progression, $P=\prod_{i}p_{i}$

Comment: I would say that in this case it is almost certainly purely coincidental. The fact that there are two well-separated “doublets” is likely not meaningful at all. In fact, the widths, separations, and relative intensities of these peaks are not identical, so this correlation is almost certainly spurious. Perhaps I am wrong and there is some modest underlying symmetry argument to be made here, but I sadly don’t think there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In high resolution any resemblance would disappear.

The spectrum shown results from rotovibrational modes. C-H stretch modes have wave numbers of about 3000 cm$^{-1}$. The spectrum at 1000 cm$^{-1}$ is due to CH3 bending modes, but for details see https://hal.sorbonne-universite.fr/hal-02017704/document.

A more complete answer would encounter paywalls.